# Javascript, any way that setTimeout might be called despite being clearTImeout? Getting that behaviour

Tags: javascript, html

Example is hard to give, because it's the first time this occurs and user specific.

I've added a clear flag now to discover that the timeout hasn't indeed been cleared, but I am puzzled as to why it is still firing.

I am on **Chrome 60.3.xyz**

The numbers are the same. Could I be clearing something else ?

Comment: "user specific" indicates (most likely) a race condition. You are probably clearing after the callback has executed.

Comment: Logging says a different order though, although that could be wrong. Race condition? I thought JS was synchronous. Since when do we have to worry about race conditions?

Comment: @momomo: JavaScript itself is indeed synchronous (with the one exception of promise callbacks), but many of the things we *use* it for are asynchronous, where we start something with a synchronous call that then completes later (XHR completions, timer callbacks, ...). And where there's asynchronous behavior, there's race conditions. That said, I wouldn't have thought this was down to a race condition.

Comment: You could have passed the timer id to a web worker and cleared it there. I was just grasping because there was no example given and you said it happens sporadically. Is the timeout set to a random value with lots of other things happening?

Comment: @RayToal I am tapping on a mobile device. Are those events fired through webworkers ? isn't it strange that i am able to check manually in setTimeout for a flag that it is cleared, but js implementation is not able to do the same prior to firing the function ?

Comment: @momomo: No, it's not at all strange. That could trivially be explained by scheduling the timer twice, as I described in my answer. (No, taps aren't handled by web workers. If you're not explicitly using web workers, you can disregard them as a potential cause.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you haven't shown us any code, we can only answer conceptually:

No. If you've correctly called `clearTimeout` with the handle returned by `setTimeout`, the browser **will not** call the timer callback afterward. If it were to do so, the browser's timer handling would be broken. As the Pragmatic Programmer says, [`select` isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips). Neither is Chrome's timer handling. :-)

I can only think of a couple of common errors in this regard:

- Calling `setTimeout` more than once and only remembering the last handle returned; this means you can only cancel the last timer scheduled
- Not storing the handle correctly

You might be wondering what happens if the time for the timer callback comes and the main JavaScript thread is busy doing something else; couldn't the task get queued while the thread is busy (since *browsers* aren't single-threaded, it's just that they run a single JavaScript UI thread), and then run when the thread is free even though the timer has since been cancelled?

The answer is no, because [the first thing the timer task does](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps) when it's picked up from the queue is check whether the timer has since been cancelled.

Here's a synthetic version of that; synthetic tests are a bit dodgy, of course:

```js
// Schedule a timer for 200ms from now
var handle = setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("tick");
}, 200);
// Block for 300ms; the timer subsystem could queue
// the task during that time (browsers aren't single-threaded,
// they just run a single JavaScript UI thread)
var stop = Date.now() + 300;
console.time("waiting");
while (stop > Date.now()) {
}
console.timeEnd("waiting");
// Cancel
clearTimeout(handle);
console.log("cancelled");
// There will be no "tick"
```

---

Regarding the code in [your JSBin](http://jsbin.com/fagozazaca/edit), the problem is that when the timer callback is called, `snapshot` refers to the **previous** object, not the current one (which is `last`). So of course its `cleared` flag is `true`; you set that flag when the click occurred.

To correctly see the flag, you'd need to look at `last`, not `snapshot`:

```js
var last = {};
var div = $('div');
div.on('click', function() {

  var snapshot = last;
  console.log("clearing " + snapshot.code);
  clearTimeout(snapshot.code);
  snapshot.cleared = true;
  console.log("Clear: ", snapshot.code, snapshot.cleared);

  last = {
    code: setTimeout(function() {
      if (last.cleared !== true) {
        console.log('I was never cleared in time!')
      } else {
        console.log("Exec: ", last.code, last.cleared, "WTF?");
      }
    }, 100)
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<div>tap me using mobile inspector</div>
```

Comment: Hmm ... I am not sure what your example is supposed to show, but tick doesn't fire here, as should not. My case is that setTimeout is firing despite having logged that I have cleared that code. Does setTimeout have a context I should be aware of? i am not prefexing it so I am sure it is window.setTimeout. I even tested to set a secondary flag on the stored away code object, and in setTimeout the obj.clear is true ( set it when I clear )

Comment: @momomo: It's meant to show that `tick` does not appear, yes. No, there's no other context. The **only** reason the timer would be firing is that it has not been cancelled. I understand you believe you've cancelled it, but with all due respect, barring a [mcve] demonstrating Chrome getting this wrong, It's dramatically more likely that there's an error causing you to schedule the timer twice and only cancel the second one, or other similar error in the code, than that Chrome gets timers wrong.

Comment: I can record a video of this happening. I would totally be agreeing with you normally, but I am actually storing the code in a separate object, and then I am clearing it, logging it, setting a flag to cleared, checking it in the setTimeout and it is cleared when that fires. How could that flag be true ?  I am able to avoid it with an if block. I am getting a different response in an IRC channel, "when event loops DO NOT GURANTEE ORDER OF PROCESSING".   "the context switch between two threads for one document", "would have a stellar impact"

Comment: especially on your phone" "that's why web workers work the way they do" ... i am tapping on mobile device. could the clearTimeout be called in a separate thread perhaps through another tap/call?

Comment: @momomo: The event loops in browsers **do** guarantee the order of processing, provided you understand their rules. A video would be useless. Again: What's needed is a [mcve] demonstrating the issue. I'm quite certain it's not Chrome's timer code that's at fault. And I'm sure your goal isn't to prove that it is; your goal is to find and fix the problem. The most likely way to do that is to let go of the notion the issue is in Chrome, and embrace that it's in your code.

Comment: @momomo: In terms of debugging, what I'd probably do is wrap `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` with my own functions and have `setTimeout` log the handle it's returning, and have `clearTimeout` log the handle it's clearing. I bet you see a handle that isn't cleared.

Comment: Something along these lines: https://jsfiddle.net/nzcbvL40/. Very important that the code creating the wrappers is the **first** code run on the page, before any third-party scripts or any other code of yours runs. If you use web workers or similar, you'll need to put these functions in them as well as that's an entirely different context.

Comment: @momomo: The problem is that you're looking at the **previous** snapshot. Remember that the function you're passing `setTimeout` has an *enduring reference* to the context in which it was created. In that context, `snapshot` is the *previous* object. So of course the `cleared` flag is true, even though the most recently-scheduled timer has never been cancelled.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was making an assumption of it actually being cleared by something else. I discovered the error thanks to this. I was in a brainfog but refused to take a break. Another lesson learned :(